# Transmission and deluge fail in ubuntu 16.04 LTS saving to external usb hard drive connected to another machine

Tags: permissions, 16.04, transmission, gvfs, deluge

I have transmission and deluge (trying to see if it's a problem with the app) and I'm having the same problem with both of them.  When torrenting.  I get an error `" Operation not supported (/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=192.168.1.7,user=pi/media/ "`  when downloading a file.

1) My desktop machine has the torrent program on it (deluge / transmission) and it's connected to my raspberry pi (via ssh) which has an external usb drive connected to it.

2) I'm trying to run transmission on my desktop but have all the files go to the external usb drive located / connected to my raspberry pi.  This worked on 14.04LTS but I can't seem to get it to work on 16.04 LTS.   I created the group **torgrp** and placed the users in it but still I get the `" Operation not supported (/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=192.168.1.7,user=pi/media/ "`

```
when I do a 
ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 14 pi   torgrp 4096 Apr 22 10:46 media
```

but when I download and check the rights of the file (see below)

```
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi     1485881344 Apr 22 10:46 ubuntu-16.04-desktop
```

and the download stops after about 6meg and comes back with an error.  **Please note the file size below says it's correct but it's just holding that amount of space for the full download**

I also check to see if the users were in the group

```
id pi
uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(pi) groups=1000(pi),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),105(netdev),999(input),1002(spi),1003(gpio),1004(torgrp)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: This is an odd setup with a lot of overhead. Why not install transmission/deluge daemon on my aspberry pi, and control it remotely from my desktop machine?

Comment: Seems likely it's a mount issue of either usb or sftp, and you need to narrow down which it is first but as @mikewhatever said it's a strange setup...

Comment: Not odd if you want to limit the number of machines that have access to the Internet and limit the number of ports you need to forward to different machines....The less open ports and the less machines that have access to the Internet the less attack vectors you have....Very logical if you ask me.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/transmission/+bug/1574934  Having the same issue trying to save to a smb/cifs share.

Comment: @SheldonRoss Some really strange issues with 16.04 I was able to install NFS and get it to work somewhat but it doesn't always work....waiting for them to figure out the issues.   It's starting to look like some (special) permission errors have some problems that are effecting a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with permissions and Transmission (Debian 9). Automounted cifs share in Gnome Nautilus works perfectly everywhere except Transmission.

I solved this issue by manually mounting with options as follows:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server/share /mountpath -o user=cifs_user,password=cifs_pw,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8
```

`uid` and `gid` are those of the user you log in as and can be obtained by running

```
id
```

or

```
cat /etc/passwd
```